# Simulating the change in enzyme returns false

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm writing a test to check if a checkbox is disabled after it's checked. It works in the UI but the test still returns that a a checked prop is false.

```
describe("<RecommendRetailer/>", () => {
  mockUseDispatch();
  mockUseSelector();

  const testProps = {
    message: null,
    isCheckbox: null,
  };
  mockUseSelector();
  let wrapper = mount(<RecommendRetailer {...testProps} />);

it("Checkbox should be disabled when checkbox is clicked", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ isCheckbox: true });
    wrapper.find(Checkbox).find("input").simulate("change");
    console.log(wrapper.find("input").debug());
        expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("checked")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The result in enzyme:
Expected: true
Received: false

Comment: Where's your wrapper ?

Comment: It's at the beginning with a describes method. Just updated the code